# How to use Remote Shared Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, client-side, server-side, shared-objects

I'm trying to use a remote shared object to send data messages between the client and server using the sharedobject.send method for a chat application. 
I am really having difficulty understanding the documentations. The code i attempted to use simply didn't work.

Can someone be kind enough to show me the relevant API calls? And, take a close inspection at my code and tell me were exactly i am going wrong?

Thank You.

Client-Side

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.SyncEvent;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.connect("rtmfp://fms/exampledomain");

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netHandler);

function netHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
        trace("Your Connected");

        //Creating the sharedobject
        var my_so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("users", nc.uri, false);

        my_so.connect(nc);

        my_so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, syncHandler);

        my_so.setProperty("users");

        my_so.setDirty("users");

        function syncHandler(event:SyncEvent):void {
            var changelist:Array = event.changeList;
        }

        my_so.send function sendMessage(str){
```

Server-Side

```
application.onConnect(clientObj)() {
    application.acceptConnection(clientObj) {
        trace("connected up");
    }

    var my_so = SharedObject.getRemote("users", false);
    my_so.send("Hello user", "Its only a test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After editing your question, it looks like some code is missing in your client-side sample.

From what I see, you don't need the client-side code for your example to work. You can call the `send()` method directly from the client. But to test whether it works or not, you will need to have two clients connected.

About your `NetConnection` or your `SharedObject`, make sure you add your event listeners before you call the `connect()` method.

If what you want to achieve is simply sharing data between clients, then you don't even need to use the `send()` method but simply set properties on your shared object. But be aware of the following:

```
my_so.setProperty("users");
```

is actually deleting the key `users` as it is the same as this:

```
my_so.setProperty("users", null);
```

Finally, you would need to call `setDirty()` in very specific cases, but not in this one. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140864/sharedobject-send-method/15676823#15676823) for a more detailed example on how to share data with SharedObjects