# AS3 How to Synchronize an event

Tags: actionscript-3, synchronization, flash-media-server, shared-objects

I am attempting to build a small chat application using a remote shared object (RSO) for FMS. My question is, how do you dispatch the SyncEvent when the RSO has been updated? Example, what I want to do is to update all the clients connected when a user enters or leaves a chatroom. I have looked for documentation on this but to no avail. If you can provide me a small example how to do this I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to dispatch the `SyncEvent` manually as it is done automatically by the shared object itself when you add a property to it or update the value of an existing property.

Note that if you set a property of your shared object to the same value it had before, no event will be dispatched.

You can find an example of use [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676823/1392790).

Comment: Thanks duTr, I appreciate the advice. Looking through the code i think i understand the majority of it. The setProperty method updates the value of a property automatically in a shared object? There is some other stuff in the code i dont quite follow but i Google search them lol.

Comment: No problems. Feel free to ask about what you don't understand here or on the example directly