# AS3: SharedObject is not visible in Administration Console

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects, flash-media-server

I created a media server with 'Adobe Media Server Starter 5' on localhost and I am able to connect to it via an AS3 AIR Application. I can see the connection from my Application called 'SimpleServer' in the 'Adobe Media Server Administration Console' and I get a positive feedback about the connection:

> Accepted a connection from IP:127.0.0.1, referrer: app:/SimpleServer.swf, pageurl:

I neither get a compile time nor a runtime error when trying to create a new SharedObject, I get no feedback at all. I am using the following  code:

```
    var shared:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("HelloWorld", "rtmp://localhost/SimpleServer");
    shared.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, syncEventHandler);
    shared.connect(nc);
```

The NetConnection is created as followed:

```
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/SimpleServer");
    nc.client = this;
```

I cannot see a SharedObject in 'View Applications' -> 'Shared Objects' and I get no feedback about the creation. It is like the object has never been created. I also tried to set properties on the SharedObject, with no effect:

```
shared.setProperty("test", false);
```

Is there a simple solution to this problem or do I have to configure advanced server stuff? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do either of the event handlers that you add above get executed? Are you waiting for the NetConnection to connect before you call `connect()` on the `SharedObject`?

Comment: It seems like the `syncEventHandler` doesn't get executed. The `netStatusHandler` gets executed and indicates the `NetConnection` as connected, so it is connected when trying to connect the `SharedObject`...

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, like I commented on duTr's answer. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

As Sunil asked in the comments, is `syncEventHandler` ever called when you run your code?

To partially answer your questions: No you don't need any specific server-side configuration to be able to retrieve a SharedObject on the client side. Simply make sure your connected to the server before performing any attempt at getting/connecting to a remote shared object.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140864/sharedobject-send-method/15676823#15676823) for some more informations

Besides, a good practive when attempting to get a remote shared object is also to use the uri from your `NetConnection` instance:

```
var shared:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("HelloWorld", nc.uri);
```

Comment: I created the SharedObject on a KeyboardEvent. I changed the variable `shared` to a global one, so it will exist over the whole runtime of the program. Now I can see the SharedObject in the Administration Console. The same effect occurs when I declare `shared` local, but push it onto a global Array or something. I also added the line `shared.client = this`, but I figured out this had no effect. Thank you for your help!